# If $\int_E f\,d\mu=\int_E g\,d\mu$ then $f=g$ a.e?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

Let $f$ and $g$ two real-valued measurable functions such that $$\int_E f\,d\mu=\int_E g\,d\mu$$

Can we say that $f=g$ a.e $(*)$? Or it is necessary that: $\forall A\in \mathcal{A}$: such that $$\int_A f\,d\mu=\int_A g\,d\mu$$

I ask this question because I did not understand why in the book "**Handbook of Multivalued Analysis Volume 1: Theory**" written by "***Shouchuan Hu***", in Theorem 3.34 (page 187)
[image]

If  $(*)$ not, what is the cause of why the author wrote this?

Comment: Just in the case of Riemann integrals, if I tell you that there are equal areas under the graphs of two *continuous* functions, do you conclude that the functions are the same?

Comment: Please sir see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not.

$$\int_{-1}^1 \sin(x) dx = \int_{-1}^1 x dx = 0$$

The second assertion is true though, but you should say what you tried before we can help you.

Comment: Please sir see my edit

Comment: Sorry can't help with that. I'm unfamiliar with all the notation involved.

Comment: Sir, if $f\leq g$ and $\int_E f d\mu=\int_E g d\mu$ then $f=g$ a.e?

Comment: Yes, that result is true!

Comment: Thank you sir, This is what i'm looking for

Comment: If it helped, you can accept the answer!

Comment: How I accept such a response

Comment: Thanks! You did fine! Have a great day/night.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\neq B$ be two sets st $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$, $f=I_A$ and $g=I_B$ their indicator functions. Then:

$$\int_E I_A\,d\mu=\int_E I_B\,d\mu \iff \mu(A)=\mu(B)$$

but clearly $f\neq g$.

Comment: I did not understand, can explain to me a little?

Comment: Please sir see my edit

Comment: I am confused as to how you are able to understand anything in that proof yet hesitate on elementary properties of integrals. I certainly don't, therefore I'm unable to help you any further, unfortunately. Sorry